# What's the meaning of ":" (colon symbol) on this Javascript code "var switchToTarget : Transform;"?

Tags: actionscript, unity-game-engine

Just wondering what's the meaning of ":" (colon symbol) on this Javascript code below?

```
var switchToTarget : Transform;
```

Thanks,
Gino

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Edit:** Reading more about [Unity](http://unity3d.com/), they have created a really *custom* implementation of JavaScript<sup>(1)</sup> for their scripting engine, which is *compiled* and it has a lot of *strongly typing* features, it looks like ActionScript/ES4, but it isn't, the language is called [UnityScript](http://code.google.com/p/unityscript/).

The colon is used by this implementation to denote the *type* of an identifier, e.g.:

```
class Person{
   var name : String;
   function Person(n : String){
      name = n;
   }
   function kiss(p : Person){
      Debug.Log(name + " kissed " +  p.name + "!");
   }
}
```

See also:

- [UnityScript Reference](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/index.html)
- [Head First into Unity with JavaScript](http://www.unifycommunity.com/wiki/index.php?title=Head_First_into_Unity_with_JavaScript)
- [Scripting Overview](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/index.html)
- [Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/)

---

The code you posted is not valid ECMAScript 3, (which is the most widely implemented standard), that will simply give you a `SyntaxError`.

The colon symbol in JavaScript has only a few usages:

1. The [object literal](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Literals#Object_Literals) syntax:

   ```
   var obj = { foo: 'bar' };
   ```
2. The [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/Conditional_Operator):

   ```
   var test = condition ? 'foo' : 'bar';
   ```
3. [Labeled statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Statements#label_Statement):

   ```
   loop1: while (true) {
     while (true) {
       break loop1; // stop outer loop
     }
   }
   ```
4. Case and default clauses of the [switch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/switch):

   ```
   switch (value) {
     case "foo":
       //..
     break;
     default:
       //..
     break;
   }
   ```
5. It can appear on [RegExp literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/core_javascript_1.5_guide/regular_expressions):

   ```
   var re = /(?:)/; // non-capturing group...
   ```

Comment: What about regex literals? ;)

Comment: @Matthew: Yes, also the `case`/`default` clauses of the `switch` statement :)

Comment: Then you also need to mention “string litarals” and “comment literals”. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

It's Adobe ActionScript, which is a derivative of javascript.

var switchToTarget : Transform; // declare var switchToTarget of type Transform.

var hello : Text = new Text(); // declare var hello of type Text and initialize it.

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/geom/Transform.html

Comment: I'd say it's more a derivative of ECMAScript.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's part of standard JavaScript, but it declares the type of a variable.

```
var myVar:Type;
```

in that flavor of JavaScript would be equivalent to this in several strongly-typed languages:

```
Type myVar;
```